# .NET Domain Model, when to eager load

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, anemic-domain-model

I'm fairly new to the whole .NET scene and I'm still trying to figure this thing out.

One thing that seems to be very advocated for is the Domain Driven Design pattern. And eager as I am to get a flying start in the .NET world and doing it proper I dived in trying to apply it to my project.

As I understand it is bad practice to give a domain object access to persistence layer functions like repositories, but then I'm really struggling on how to get around the problem of eager loading when working with heavily connected graphs. It usually ends up with having pretty much no logic in the domain model and moving all of it to a service layer which does calculations and fills the model objects with data or returns the result directly, for example `price = productService.CalculatePriceFor(product, user);` instead of `price = product.Price(user)` since the latter cannot be accomplished without eager loading the whole productgroup tree and discount matrix when first requesting the object.

What is good practice here? Implement subclasses of product where the information for getting the user price is calculated at load time and have another subclass of it when I don't need the user price?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In proper DDD you don't have any heavily connected graphs. Vaughn Vernon's article about the aggregates design should help you catch the idea.

http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/

Also consider if product and user belong to the same bounded context. I would say they don't. In different context there might be similar ideas implemented in different way, for example, in Pricing Context, the Client class might be a simple aggregate providing some rebates but no information about shipping, invoices etc. However, is Shipping Context there would be a similar user class being only an value object (with an address) within a Shipping aggregate. User class seems to be a part of Authentication Context.